# removing a div will automatically clear the memory assigned to binds and other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question was bugging me since i start working with JQuery and js,

if ad add an event to a div. let say

```
$('#myid').click(function(){alert('ho user ')} )
```

And then I delete the div from the dom.

```
$('#myid').remove()
```

there will be penalties of memory if i don't unbind the event?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) :

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery
>   data associated with the elements are removed.

You can use it without fear of memory leaks, it was specifically designed to ensure there is none.

Comment: thanks. but what happened if i remove the parent div that contain that div directly from the dom. not via JQuery.remove, then what happen?

Comment: Then it's not cleaned and you have a memory link because event handlers and data are stored in the jQuery object.

Comment: so runing a $('#mydiv').unbind will clean the events and then i can delete the dom?

Comment: Why not simply use `$('#myid').remove()` ? It would take care of **also** removing the events handlers bound to child elements.

Comment: you are right. i got the bad manner of doing html('') every time i want to clean a div. may just start doing the right way

Comment: You **can** use `html('')` without creating memory leaks : *"Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content."*. jQuery is well made enough that you don't usually make memory leaks.